# Running QGIS plugin in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm working with someone who exclusively uses ArcGIS Desktop. I run QGIS and no longer have access to a copy of ArcGIS Desktop.

Is there a way to develop a plugin in QGIS and then use it in ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: QGIS and ArcGIS are not compatible, you can share the data (shapefile/geodatabase/raster) but not the projects or layer files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mapperz says, QGIS and ArcGIS are not compatible... but where there is a will there is a way.  You could write a python routine using the GDAL libraries and that will run in both QGIS and ArcGIS and indeed completely standalone.  It is not exactly a plugin but close.